# JPA load multiple lazy collections

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have following entities:

```java
@Entity
public class ProjectEntity implements Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity =  FlowEntity.class)
    private Flow flow;
}

@Entity
public class FlowEntity implements Flow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = StepEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Step> steps;
}

@Entity
public class StepEntity implements Step {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = ResourceEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Resource> resources;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = StepRuleEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<StepRule> rules;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = ResourceTypeDataEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ResourceTypeData> resourceTypeData;
}
```

Now when I retrieve my project I want that everything is loaded. I can't make everything eager loaded because it will just slow everything down. But for this functionality I now really need everything from the project.

I read on the internet that you need to call `.size()` method on every collection and that jpa will then load the collections but it doesn't work. Plus I find it really strange that I need to do a `for` loop in my dao on every step of the flow to load the next lazy loaded collections.

My method is annotated with `@Transactional` to fetch the project and it's a default `JpaRepostitory`.

How do you do this properly?

Comment: You can either use entity graph (https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-2-define/) or JPQL fetch joins (https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#LEFT_OUTER__INNER_JOIN_FETCH_)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally @OneToMany must have Lazy loaded associations by default. Therefore, in class **FlowEntity**, steps must be fetched lazily. Further, as shown in the answer you can use JPQL Join FETCH to eagerly load required associations.